# Raspberry Pi Apache web server to be able to access online

Tags: apache, web, server

I've got a raspberry pi with the ip lets just say X. My IP address is Y.

My routers port forwarding configuration looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgZmD.png).

Can someone please help me how can I access my webserver from the internet? On LAN I am able to access it with http://X/index.php but I am stuck at this point.
Sorry if I cannot formulate my worlds well, I am pretty new to this whole web server thing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is your public ip static or dynamic? [Here is how to check it](https://www.techbout.com/check-ip-static-dynamic-4135/)

If it is dynamic, (almost) tough luck!

If it is static, you need to set up port forwarding. In essence, configure your rooter to forward all traffic on port 80 (or whatever) to your raspberry. Exact steps vary but try googling "  forward port 80" for instructions.

When forwarding is set, you should be able to access the Raspberry from outside your LAN.

Comment: It is dynamic, does it mean i cant portforward?

Comment: You still can, BUT dynamic addresses change frequently, so your ip address "Y" won't stay the same and will change without notice.

Comment: There are services like https://www.noip.com/ that offers a workaround for dynamic IPs.